# Dependency Injection in Scala Guice - Passing Parameters

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, guice

I have a pretty simple scenario to solve using DI, but I am unable to find a proper example/documentation to get me through. I'm new to Scala/Guice world.

The current components look like this

```
trait Foo {
}

class FooImpl extends A {

}

trait Bar {
   val description: String
}

class BarImpl(val description: String) extends Bar {

}
```

Now, I have a dependency between Foo and Bar.
So, usually the code would look like this

```
class FooImpl extends Foo {
  Bar bar = createBar("Random Bar Value!")
}
```

where `createBar("Bar!")` simply returns `new BarImpl("Random Bar Value")`. Of course, I'm removing the factory/helper for brevity.

I realize, the moment I use "new", this is out of the DI paradigm. I want to ensure that Bar can be injected into FooImpl based on a parameter. Sort of like using a Factory. How do we use DI in the Scala/Guice world.

I had a look at AssistedInjection/Named Parameters, but I could not understand how the usage would end up being like. I assume that is the best way to go, but couldn't understand how it should be written/tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this is what worked for me, finally. Re-writing these steps for anyone who wants to deal with Scala Based Assisted Injection.

Foo may require Bar, but what really needs to get injected, is a BarFactory, and not Bar.

A BarFactory needs to be created, but the implementation can be left to Guice. This is where it gets tricky.

```
trait BarFactory {
  def create(msg:String):Bar
}
```

So let's revisit Foo and Bar:

```
@ImplementedBy(classOf[FooImpl])
trait Foo {
  def getBar(msg: String): Bar
}

class FooImpl @Inject() (barFactory: BarFactory) extends Foo {
  override def getBar(msg: String): Bar = {
    barFactory.create(msg)
  }
}

@ImplementedBy(classOf[BarImpl])
trait Bar {
  def echo() : String
}

//Note that we use the @Assisted Annotation Here.
class BarImpl @Inject() (@Assisted msg: String) extends Bar {
  override def echo(): String = msg
}
```

Creating the actual factory is done as part of a Module

```
class TempModule extends AbstractModule {
  override def configure(): Unit = {
    install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
      .implement(classOf[Bar], classOf[BarImpl])
      .build(classOf[BarFactory]))
  }
}
```

And once started, the Factory Implementation will be provided by Guice, and you should be able to create your actual implementation using the Factory.